# Is it possible to increase the number of databases in AWS Elasticache Redis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

By default it is configured to have 16 databases, but I need to increase that number and I don't know how to do it.

If anyone has an idea how to do this I would greatly appreciate it since I have not found information in the documentation.

**UPDATE**:

In the parameter group settings I found where the values are modified, but it says that "databases" is not modifiable, also, in the comments **Guy Royse** (thanks for reply) mentions that he doubts that it can be modified

Parameter Group Settings:

[image: Parameter Group Settings]

Comment: Redis doesn't allow you to set that via the CONFIG SET command. It can be set in the redis.conf file by changing the `databases` property but I doubt Elasticache (or any cloud provider) would give you access to that.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the number of `databases` in the parameter group if the parameter group is not associated with any cache clusters. See the [Redis-specific parameters page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/ParameterGroups.Redis.html#ParameterGroups.Redis.3-2-4.Changed) in the documentation.

Note this will only work when you create a new cache cluster. You cannot modify the parameter group of an existing cache cluster to a new parameter group with a different `databases` value.

To create a cache cluster with an increased number of Redis databases:

1. Create a new parameter group. For example, using the aws cli:

```
REGION=eu-west-1
NUM_OF_DBS=32
PARAM_GROUP_NAME=modify-databases
CACHE_PARAM_GRP_FAMILY=redis7

aws elasticache create-cache-parameter-group \
  --cache-parameter-group-name $PARAM_GROUP_NAME \
  --cache-parameter-group-family $CACHE_PARAM_GRP_FAMILY \
  --description "" \
  --region $REGION
```

2. Modify the value of the `databases` parameter

```
aws elasticache modify-cache-parameter-group \
  --cache-parameter-group-name $PARAM_GROUP_NAME \
  --parameter-name-values "ParameterName=databases,  ParameterValue=$NUM_OF_DBS" \
  --region $REGION
```

3. Create a new Redis cluster and associate it with the new cache parameter group